# How to fix this for loop to compare two char arrays?

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to C# and still learning about arrays. I got a problem where I have to compare two strings, and what I have to compare is how many times the same letter is in the same place in both strings. I made a for loop and an if statement that I feel should work, but it doesn't add to the counter and I can't see the problem myself.

I've searched how to compare char arrays and i found that the for loop I have would probably be best for this problem, but after it stopped working I'm not sure what I should do. I've gone into the debugging mode on visual studio and looked at the values as the code runs, and everything seems fine up until the if statement, which I think is the source of the problem I have.

```
//counter for the answer: how many parking spaces shared
            int counter = 0;

            //int for the number of spaces
            int num = 0;
            //takes number from textbox into num
            int.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out num);

            //parking spaces from first day
            string yesterday = txtYesterday.Text;

            //parking spaces from second day
            string today = txtToday.Text;

            //my idea was to put both days into char arrays and compare 
each spot in a for loop
            char[] y = yesterday.ToCharArray();
            char[] t = today.ToCharArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                //so if the first spot is the same as the first spot on the 
other day, and the spot has the correct letter then it should work

                if(y[i] == t[i] && y[i].Equals("C"))
                {
                    counter++;
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show(counter.ToString());
```

an example input would be

3

.CC

..C

the answer should be 1, because one spot was occupied on both days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the following line

```
if(y[i] == t[i] && y[i].Equals("C"))
```

You are taking a character at time in your loop. So it needs to be compare with a character rather than string.

```
if(y[i] == t[i] && y[i].Equals('C'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have char array so you'll need to see if `y[i].Equals("C")` by comparing chars not strings:

```
y[i].Equals('C')
```